# How to find function expression from the graph?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I have two variables $a$ and $b$. I have series of values for $a$ and series of values for $b$.

Then I apply a simple formula on $a$ and $b$

point $j=\frac{a-b}{a}$ when $a>b$ or $\frac{b-a}{b}$ when $b>a$.

Lets say when $a[10]=32$ and $b[10]=34$.  then $j[10]=\frac{34-32}{34}=0.058$

Accumulating all these points j, I get the attached graph.[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugVHf.png)

Now my question-if I have to express the graph in terms of a function notation what should it be?

$f(a,b)=\frac{a-b}{a}$ when $a>b$ 
$f(a,b)=\frac{b-a}{b}$ when $b>a$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is correct notation. You could also use:
\begin{align*}
f(a,b) =
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
\frac{a-b}{a} & \text{if } a>b \\
\frac{b-a}{b} & \text{if } b<a
\end{matrix}
\right.
\end{align*}
Note, however, that you haven't covered the cases $a=b$, $0=a>b$, or $0=b>a$.

Comment: thanks a lot..if I have to find the rate of change of the output of the function- then how do I do it?

Comment: Do you mean take the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $a$ or $b$?

Comment: I meant if over time 't' i try to find slope of 'j'

Comment: i wanted to find maxima and minima of the graph made from 'j' , therefore the ask of how to find the slope(rate of change) for the values of  'j'

Comment: So, you have functions $a(t)$,$b(t)$, and $f(a,b)$, and you want to find the slope of the function $j(t) = f(a(t),b(t))$?

Comment: I'd suggest asking a new question with this more detailed information; you can comment a link here so I see it if you'd like my input.

Comment: Thanks a lot.I have created another question based on my query as you asked me-your inputs would really help me here.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2878150/how-to-find-function-expression-from-the-graph-and-consequently-find-inflection